# Custom UITableViewCell never showing up with AutoLayout self-sizing

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've been trying to get a very basic self-sizing UITableViewCell to show up in a table, but the custom cell won't even show up.

I am using iOS 8, and not worrying about implementing the delegate height functions as a result.  My code for the UITableView works when I use a default UITableViewCell, so I'm assuming the problem is in my UITableViewCell, but it's so simple I'm not sure how that could be the case.

Here's the cell with its constraints (to the content view - I have tried tweaking priorities up/down, but nothing has helped):
[image: Very bright label]

Here is the nib loading code in the TableViewController:

```
[submissionTable registerNib: [UINib nibWithNibName:@"SimpleCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SimpleCell"];

// These two lines are required for autolayout sizing:
submissionTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
submissionTable.estimatedRowHeight = 44;
```

And here is the code for the UITableViewCell (I said it was simple!)

```
class SimpleCell: UITableViewCell   {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier);
        self.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder);
        self.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    }
}
```

Finally, here is the rather depressing (and unexpected) outcome:
[image: Huge depressing table cell]

With the following unsatisfiable constraints as two errors.  The thing is, these seem pretty simple to satisfy:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7aef78b0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7a79fae0.trailingMargin == UILabel:0x7ae36b10'Label label label label l...'.trailing>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7aef78e0 UILabel:0x7ae36b10'Label label label label l...'.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7a79fae0.leadingMargin>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a94db00 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7a79fae0(0)]>"
```

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7aef6250 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7a79fae0.bottomMargin == UILabel:0x7ae36b10'Label label label label l...'.bottom>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7aef6280 UILabel:0x7ae36b10'Label label label label l...'.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7a79fae0.topMargin>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7a94db30 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7a79fae0(0.5)]>"
```

**NOTE/EDIT:**
I accepted the answer below because of point #1.  For some reason, setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false) actually **broke** it.

Comment: Objective-C or swift?

Comment: I see you have code from both, is the view controllers objc and I guess the cell is swift? or is the objc you show above an error?

Comment: do you use storyboard or xib

Comment: I am using xib files for the views and cells.  The viewcontroller with is legacy and is written in Objective-C.  It sets the nib for the table cell, which is written in swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you are using autolayout with xib ,those code is unnessary.

   self.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false).
2. I have found that H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7a79fae0(0)]>" ,

this means your contentView's Height is 0.
Maybe something wrong with your CellHeight Method.
Try to implement TableViewDelegate  to return cell's Height instead of Using UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: I didn't want to implement the delegate to compute the row height, that was the whole point of doing it with UITableViewAutomatic dimension.  It seems like I should have to set the translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints for this view since it's the only one loaded from this xib, and doesn't have it automatically set (I did check).

Comment: So strangely enough, it works if translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is **true** on the cell, even though it's false on the built-in UITableViewCell.  Huh!?  So that line is not only unnecessary, it was causing the problems.  Curioser and curioser.